# boost 1.73.0 build issue - error: feature already defined

Tags: c++, boost, building

When using boost 1.73.0 my build breaks, I get this error:

```
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/feature.jam:140: in feature from module feature
error: feature already defined:
error: in feature declaration:
error: feature "lto" : "off" "on" "gold" : "composite" "propagated" "link-incompatible"
Jamfile:56: in load-aux from module Jamfile</Users/gubatron/workspace.frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/swig>
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:378: in load-jamfile from module project
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load from module project
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:142: in project.find from module project
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:618: in load from module build-system
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
/Users/gubatron/src/boost_1_73_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

[The refered JamFile](https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/blob/master/swig/Jamfile) looks like this around line 56:

```
feature lto : off on gold : composite propagated link-incompatible ;
feature.compose <lto>on : <cxxflags>-flto <linkflags>-flto ;
feature.compose <lto>gold : <cxxflags>-flto <linkflags>-flto
    <linkflags>-fuse-ld=gold ;
```

I wonder if [these changes](https://github.com/boostorg/build/releases/tag/4.1.0) had someting to do with this breaking, no longer needed to specify these options? Any help from someone that knows boost building in and out would be very helpful.

Comment: for now I couldn't figure out what was wrong with this, the solution to continue to build without this "lto" feature at all, luckily our build wasn't using iLnk Time Optimization

Comment: Looks like a bug report against boost.build.